# Change sender account ms outlook in python 3

Tags: outlook, python-3.6, pywin32

I have 2 accounts in ms outlook ('user1@test.com' - default profile ,'user2@test.com') and i'm trying to sent a message by python using the non-default account. Here is my code:

```
Import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.application')

mess = app.CreateItem(0)
mess.to = 'user2@test.com'
mess.subject = 'hi'
mess.SendUsingAccount = 'user2@test.com'
mess.Send()
```

And outlook sent from account 'user1@test.com', not from 'user2@test.com'. How to change an account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property allows setting an [Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.account) object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent.

```
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
oacctouse = None
for oacc in o.Session.Accounts:
    if oacc.SmtpAddress == "user2@test.com":
        oacctouse = oacc
        break
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
if oacctouse:
    Msg._oleobj_.Invoke(*(64209, 0, 8, 0, oacctouse))  # Msg.SendUsingAccount = oacctouse

if to:
    Msg.To = ";".join(to)
if cc:
    Msg.CC = ";".join(cc)
if bcc:
    Msg.BCC = ";".join(bcc)

Msg.HTMLBody = ""

Msg.Send()
```

Comment: Eugene, when i try to see Session.Accounts has only one email, but when i go to my outlook application has two, anyway i try to set manually oacctouse if i use the uncommented code i get this error (com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)) if i try the commented code this uses my primary e-mail, any clues?

Comment: Hi, I have similar problem. Outlook has two accounts but in python object, I see only one account. Any luck in resolving this issue? How do we identify the other account which is not shown in python?

Comment: Are you sure that you have actually have got two accounts configured? Is there any chance that you have got two stores (and one of them is shared)? Can you share a screenshot of the accounts configuration window?